# The edges/corners of shapes I draw in TikZ don't line up correctly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a hexagon composed of two trapezoids. I would like the edges of the line forming the shape to be joined/mitered properly, and for the middle line of the hexagon to be share by both trapezoids.

The second problem can be solved, sort of, by drawing the whole thing as a single line. The problem is that I need two shapes so I can fill the bottom one with a different color. However, the mitering problem still remains even with this approach.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\node ()
\draw (0,0) (0:1) -- (60:1) -- (120:1) -- (180:1) -- cycle;
\draw (0,0) (180:1) -- (240:1) -- (300:1) -- (360:1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you are using.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you can show us the code you already have you might be able to get help more quickly. That is something to keep in mind for the future though, since Gonzalo Medina has already given a nice answer.

Comment: Right, let me update that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `line join=round` could help; a comparison with and without it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4pt,cyan]
\filldraw[fill=orange!20]
  (0,0) -- ++(0:4) -- ++(120:2) -- ++(180:2) -- cycle; 
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20]
  (0,0) -- ++(0:4) -- ++(-120:2) -- ++(180:2) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=4pt,cyan,line join=round]
\filldraw[fill=orange!20]
  (0,0) -- ++(0:4) -- ++(120:2) -- ++(180:2) -- cycle; 
\filldraw[fill=yellow!20]
  (0,0) -- ++(0:4) -- ++(-120:2) -- ++(180:2) -- cycle; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!